# Returning a value of zero when I'm trying to total a price within a promise

Tags: javascript, scope, es6-promise

Im trying to pull data from an API(firebase) and Im getting back the correct data but when i try and resolve the final Price in the Promise I keep getting a value of 0. I've tried moving around the original variable to change the scope and nothing has helped so far.

```
const staffTotalPrices = (eventFirebaseKey) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  eventStaff.getEventStaff(eventFirebaseKey).then((staffArray) => {
    let staffTotal = 0;
    staffArray.forEach((staff) => {
      staffData.getSingleStaff(staff.staffUid).then((staffObject) => {
        staffTotal += parseInt(staffObject.price, 10);
        return staffTotal;
      });
    });
    resolve(staffTotal);
  }).catch((error) => reject(error));
});
```

I've been pushing it to an empty array, then doing a .reduce array method to add the totals, but I'm having to put a timeout when calling it/reducing it just to wait on the API response

Answer (score 1):

In your `forEach` loop you are calling an async function but not awaiting its result. So you are calling `resolve(staffTotal)` before any of the `staffData.getSingleStaff` resolved.

You could for instance do a  [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) which will execute all promises and resolve with an array of the results.

```
const staffTotalPrices = (eventFirebaseKey) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  eventStaff.getEventStaff(eventFirebaseKey)
    //execute getSingleStaff for all elements in the array and resolve when all are resolved
    .then(staffArray => Promise.all(staffArray.map(staff => staffData.getSingleStaff(staff.staffUid))))
    //sum up the prices in the staffObjects array with reduce
    .then(staffObjects => staffObjects.reduce((a,c) => parseInt(a.price, 10) + parseInt(c.price, 10), 0))
    //resolve the promise with the sum
    .then(totalStaff => resolve(totalStaff));
    .catch((error) => reject(error));
});
```

Another possibility would be, keeping a count of resolved promises inside the forEach loop. And once, all promises have resolved, also resolve the outer promise. But then of course, you will also need to catch a reject of the inner promises, as otherwise if one of them rejects your promise might stay in pending state.

```
const staffTotalPrices = (eventFirebaseKey) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  eventStaff.getEventStaff(eventFirebaseKey).then((staffArray) => {
    let staffTotal = 0; let resolveCounter = 0;
    staffArray.forEach((staff) => {
      staffData.getSingleStaff(staff.staffUid)
        .then((staffObject) => {
          staffTotal += parseInt(staffObject.price, 10);
          if (++resolveCounter == staffArray.length) 
            resolve(staffTotal);
        })
        .catch(e => reject(e));
    });
  }).catch((error) => reject(error));
});
```